# Synonym request: zombie, zombies, defunct

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The tags [zombie](/questions/tagged/zombie), [zombies](/questions/tagged/zombies) and [defunct](/questions/tagged/defunct) are all about [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). Please make them synonyms.

[zombie.js](/questions/tagged/zombie.js) and [nszombie](/questions/tagged/nszombie) are unrelated concepts. Maybe `zombie-process` (which doesn't currently exist) would be a better name for the unix concept, to avoid confusion?

There's also a [nszombieenabled](/questions/tagged/nszombieenabled) which looks like it may be a synonym of [nszombie](/questions/tagged/nszombie), but I'm not familiar enough with the topic to tell for sure.

Comment: I'd vote for `zombie-process`.

Comment: I can verify that nszombie and nszombieenabled are indeed references to the same topic (a debugging setting for Objective-C programming)

Comment: You got plenty of rep to do this yourself.  Why spam meta about it?

Comment: @Hans No, I don't have enough rep in any of these tags to suggest a synonym. Granted, if I rembember the rules correctly, the [6 users who have ≥6 answer upvotes in that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/zombies/topusers) can band together and create the synonym. But that's a stretch. What's wrong with synonym requests on meta, especially when the best name is up for discussion?

Comment: brains. brains. brains.

Comment: NZZombieEnabled should be renamed to NSZombie, not the other way around.